# how to use springboot validator with freemarker?

Tags: validation, spring-boot, freemarker

trying to use native springboot validator with freemarker to check input whether correct or not.
but I got ftl error in my front page.
code showing below:
pojo

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer"/*, indexes = {@Index(name = "INX_CUSTOMER_NO", columnList = "no")}*/)
public class CustomerEntity extends BaseEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
Long id;
@Column(name = "name")
@NotBlank(message = "{notBlank}")
String name;
```

controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/static/cust_add.html",method = {RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST})
public ModelAndView add(@Valid CustomerEntity cust, BindingResult bindingResult, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("cust", cust);
    mv.setViewName("/static/cust_add");
    return mv;
}
```

ftl

```
  <form action="/crm/static/cust_check.html" class="form-ajax-file">
    <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4" bordercolor="#666666">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#eeeeee">add customer info</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="150" align="right">customerName:</td>
            <td>
                <@spring.bind "cust.name"/>
                <input type="text" id="name" class="tr-width"/>
            </td>
            <td><@spring.showErrors ""/></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
```

and the error

```
FreeMarker template error (DEBUG mode; use RETHROW in production!): The following has evaluated to null or missing: ==> spring [in template "static/cust_add.ftl" at line 20, column 19] ----
```

really need some help

Comment: Remove the `RedirectAttributes` you aren't redirecting and because you are using `ModelAndView` you are destroying the internal model. Just return a `String` with the name of the view.

Comment: still got this error